# WPF - Initializing Window.Owner to a Window created on a different thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

The window `_splash` is created on a different thread.

```
MainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
MainWindow.Owner = _splash; // Throw: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
```

How can I make this code work ?

Comment: A: Don't create windows on background threads.

Comment: Never manipulate the UI on a background thread. I am not aware about other operating systems, but in Win32 applications using standard controls that's just not gonna work.

Comment: WPF is perfectly capable of having multiple UI threads, but *any* Windows application, whether WPF or not, will have problems if you try to make a window from one thread be owned by a window from another thread. Windows attaches the thread input between the two threads and you lose all the benefits of multithreading. If you need Owner, don't create UI on multiple different threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to sound crass, but you fix it by running the splash screen on the UI thread running the main window.  Why does the splash screen need its own thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do any long-running work on the UI thread. Use `BackgroundWorker`s or something like [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) to make this easy.
2. Create all `Window` instances on the UI thread.